# How can I detect an event on a particular layer in a layer list?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

Somewhat of a newb question, but I'm hoping this can be done.

I have an image layer list that looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/start_comp" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background" />
</layer-list>
```

I would like to be able use an OnClickListener (or whatever) to detect when one of the drawables is tapped (start_comp).  How can I do this beautiful act of Android magic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Drawables do not receive click events, whether they are `layer-list` or any other type of drawable.

Instead, you may wish to pursue layering two *widgets* on top of each other, using a container that supports Z-axis ordering, like `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`. For example, here is a `RelativeLayout` supporting two layered `Button` widgets:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/big"
                android:textSize="120dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/small"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Containers/RelativeOverlap))

Comment: Thanks... that was quick and easy.